# HTTP server and its directories

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I have a custom HTTP web server, whenever I browse to it, let say: http://hotname:port it redirects to this:

http://hotname:port/base

The server runs from: /home/user/app_web/bin/start.pl

I have a directory of HTMLs listed in: /home/user/app_web/static

while the server is running, one of the request I send to him is an HTML with a body having this img:

```
<img src="../static/page.html">
```

this page loads fine, but of the images in it, doesnt, which is in: "/home/user/app_web/static/image/1.jpg"

when I look at the HTML site the pages has loaded, it looks like:

http://hotname:port/base/../home/user/app_web/static/image/1.jpg"

I have no idea what am I doing wrong, also, I'm a newbie when it comes to web.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML image tag for 1.jpg? Also a snippet of your code that parses the tag and determines the on-disk file location would be useful.

Comment: image tag updated, the http server, from what I know uses anyevent::socket tcp_server method call, I dont have the code here at the moment (not on the computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML file location is

> /home/user/app_web/static/page.html

and the image is in

> /home/user/app_web/static/image/1.jpg

Then try changing the image tag to:

```
<img src="image/1.jpg">
```

URLs will be worked out relative to the HTML file.

(Since "static" is part of the folder location and *not* the URL, as far as I can see, you should never have to include "static" in the URL.)

Comment: For some reason, I tried that in the first place, and it didnt work. seems like that /base the HTTP server redirects to is located in: /var/webapp/   for which I dont have permissions. how do I know that its there? there is an icon there, when I replaced the image in my HTML with that icon like: src="iconname.ico" it worked fine.

Comment: OK. What's the URL you use to visit page.html?

Comment: "h t t p://hotname:port"   and then its automatically redirects to: "h t t p://hotname:port/base"

Comment: Can you try: http://hotname:port/base/page.html (whatever you page.html is called). Also, try visiting http://hotname:port/base/image/ in a browser.